# Show headers on empty data source in SPGridView

Tags: 2010, web-part, spgridview

I have a webpart with SPGridView. I created column dynamic.

This works fine when I have data, but when no rows are returned then I just get a blank spot where the grid should be.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is work for me.

```
public void BuildNoRecords(GridView gridView, DataSet ds)
{
  try {
   if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count == 0) {
   ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(ds.Tables(0).NewRow());
   gridView.DataSource = ds;
   gridView.DataBind();
   int columnCount = gridView.Rows(0).Cells.Count;
   gridView.Rows(0).Cells.Clear();
   gridView.Rows(0).Cells.Add(new TableCell());
   gridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).ColumnSpan = columnCount;
   gridView.Rows(0).Cells(0).Text = "No Records Found.";
 }
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These 3 members are used to handle EmptyData in the SPGridView.

1. EmptyDataRowStyle
2. EmptyDataTemplate
3. EmptyDataText

Also check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/bk81h1e5) for more info

**Update 1**: If you just want to show the headers even though there are no data, use the [ShowHeaderWhenEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty) property.

**Update 2**: Check the list of properties and members for the [SPGridView here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview_members.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but i want show header (Example listwebpart).

Comment: @ar.gorgin Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks, i use this property but don't show header